# Replace bunch of files maintaining path

Tags: command-line, cp, mv

I have directory **A** and **B**. Each of them contains another directory with **item.json** inside.
Only **item.json** file is persistent in directories so I can't copy-paste the directories.

A:

```
./path/Item A/item.json
./path/Item B/item.json
...
./path/Item Z/item.json
```

B:

```
./new/Item A/item.json
./new/Item B/item.json
...
./new/Item Z/item.json
```

How should I copy all item.json files from `./path/` to appropriate folders in `./new` ?

**My solution:**

To get directories

```
ls -l ./path | grep "^d" | cut -d' ' -f 16
```

So then I can use the results as:

```
for i in `ls -l ./path | grep "^d" | cut -d' ' -f 16`; echo "Dir: $i"; done
```

So I can do `cp` with them

```
for i in `ls -l ./path | grep "^d" | cut -d' ' -f 16`; cp "$i/item.json" "../new/$i/item.json" ; done
```

And this solution is ok, but I believe there's much more elegant way.

Comment: `find ./path -type d -exec cp -rt ./new {} +`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine! If you like to see alternatives, my suggestion is just `cp`!

I presume you want to copy just "item.json" files and that you can have other
contents not to be copied.

```
cd path; cp --parents */item.json ../new
```

Answer (score 2):

Below one liner should help you with it.

```
$ find ./path/ -type f -exec bash -c 'cp $0 ${0/path/new}' {} \;
```

Here the `find` command searches for all text file within the `./path/` directory. When a file is found it invokes a small bash script which copies that file to the destination `/new/` directory by just replacing string from `path` to `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cpio` (or `tar`, but IMHO it slower and don't have `-p` option like cpio do)! It maintains permissions, dates, etc. (if asked to) and of course maintains directory structure.

I.e.: `cd path ; find . | cpio -pvmd ../new`